# Where is my desktop background slideshow stored?

Tags: windows, desktop, slideshow

I switched laptops a few years ago and somehow Windows was able to move my old deskstop slideshow onto my new computer. I've recently decided I wanted to change my background, however I do not want to delete the pictures in the slideshow. (I do not have the pictures stored elsewhere, so if I change my background, I am afraid I will lose the pictures that are currently on the slideshow.

Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: You can at least get the currently active image. It is stored here: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles`

Comment: @Robert if you delete the currently active image then Windows simply replaces it with the next active image when the slideshow cycles to the next image.